# How do add the WiXNetFx extension?

Tags: installation, wix, .net-4.8

I am creating an installer. I have a setup project for the same along with a bootstrapper project which consists of all my pre requisites. However, I would like to check if the pre requisites (with the specified version) are already installed in my system, and only if they aren't installed I would like to go ahead for the same. I found few sources online which said that I could use WiXNetFx extension to achieve the same. However in my VS 2022 I am unable to see any such extension. So now I am clueless how to go about with this...
Is the extension no longer in use? If so, is there any other way I could achieve what I want.

Is the extension no longer in use? If so, is there any other way I could achieve what I want.
Ps the pre requisites I am referring to are .NET Framework 4.8 and Keysight Open TAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still there. In WiX v3, it's ProgramFilesFolder\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll. In WiX v4, it's [WixToolset.Netfx.wixext](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WixToolset.Netfx.wixext).